# Should SVG `viewbox` be defined once in `symbol`, or each time an SVG is `used`?

Tags: html, svg

According to [some](https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/) of the [tutorials](https://nucleoapp.com/how-to-create-an-icon-system-using-svg-symbols/) I've read, when inserting an SVG `<symbol>` with `<use>` the `viewBox` property only needs to be defined once - in the `<symbol>` tag.

This nominally works okay, but the contents of the `<use>` element overflow the parent `<svg>` by a fairly large factor (apparently always a scale of the parent svg element's size, although it seems to vary depending on CSS styles). This doesn't appear to cause any actual problems (the overflow's hidden, so there are no unwanted scrollbars or layout problems), but somehow it feels 'wrong'.

Then there's the answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204790/height-auto-on-svg-not-working) asked here last year which recommends removing the `viewbox` property from the `<symbol>` element entirely and declaring it in the `<svg>` tags instead. Doing things this way means everything is displayed 100% as it should be, but from what I gathered one of the good things about the `<symbol>` tag is it should mean the `viewbox` only needs to be declared once rather than on every insertion.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Creak/cq63afxr/) to try and compare different use cases.

Is there a correct way of doing things? Is that overflow normal and to be ignored? Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

**Edit:** Looks like when the `viewbox` attribute is only set in `<symbol>` it scales up the entire parent svg tag as well. Should the SVG dimensions be explicitly set with each `use`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: If you do not specify any viewBox attribute to the svg tag, it will not scale properly whatever the `height` or `width` value.

As you can have several symbols in the same SVG such as (simplified code)

```
<svg>
<use href="somePath#symbol1"></use>
<use href="somePath#symbol2"></use>
</svg>
```

Each symbol can have its own size*. Now the SVG tag (the root) also needs to know which size* should be used. For this reason, you have to set a viewBox on the SVG tag itself.

*we should not call it 'size' but more 'area', 'bounding box' or simply 'view box'

If you were using only one symbol, you will very likely choose the same viewBox as the targetted symbol's. In this manner, the SVG will scale like an `<img>`

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<use href="somePath#anIcon32x32"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is the best explanation that I could find regarding this behavior.

Comment: which view box to use in case the SVG contains more symbols?

Comment: Does [this](https://codepen.io/falconx/pen/ExGoXyb) answer your question ?